# Could not find play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

When i try ro run android application in android studio i get this error :

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/17.0.0/play-services-ads-identifier-17.0.0.jar
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

i add this line to build.gradle file but it's not work.

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved with update gradle and android studio.

Comment: to which version?

Answer (score 0):

i add this to gradle and solved!!

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0"